# ctrlKey on windows = cmdKey (metaKey) on mac

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2

This might be a silly question but I haven't found the answer so far.
The problem I'm facing is that I need the Cmd key from mac (metaKey) when is pressed to mimic the behaivour of the Ctrl key.

I need this in order to make my shortcuts run in the next way :

When on windows : Ctrl + O opens a new window

When on mac : Cmd + O opens a new window

Basically, whenever Cmd is pressed on mac, it should be interpreted as Ctrl is pressed.

I mention the fact that my shortcuts work with Ctrl both on Mac & Windows, but when I try to use the metakey it simply won't work, and I also have a function which detects the OS, so I know if I am either on mac or windows.

Thanks!

Comment: You will have to implement your own logic here: either write your own keypress modifier, or manually check the `e.ctrlKey` or `e.metaKey` depending on the OS detected.

Comment: https://keycode.info could be helpful for debugging/testing purposes of your shortcuts btw.

Comment: @Terry can you please be more specific when you say to manually check the key based on the OS?

Comment: Not all the OS send the same keycode, it also depends of your keyboard, mapping etc. Hence why keycode.info may be nice as a test to see what is actually happening exactly on the key code.

Comment: for the meta left key which matter the most for me looks like it's the same on windows / mac (keyCode 91)

Comment: Didn't tried it myself, but there are 3 mains OSes and I'm pretty sure it's not the same for all of them too. I mean, you could double-check pretty quickly.

Comment: just did it, it's 91 :D (on chrome, because that's the only browser that is going to be used)